# "Distinct" column in SQL query

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

> SELECT id, EmpNo
>   FROM  EmployeesTable

EmpNo can be the same for 1 or more records in the results of the above query. I now want to add another column derived from EmpNo(lets call it EmpNo2) but only returning distinct values of EmpNo.

For example if the above query returns 100 records but there are 69 distinct EmpNo values and i modify the query to

```
SELECT id, EmpNo, Distinct EmpNo2
FROM  EmployeesTable EmpNo
```

, 
i want all the 100 rows to be returned but the last column EmpNo2 should return 69 distinct values of EmpNo field.

But as already know, using distinct in that way results into an error but i want to implement such functionality - and a subquery is not helping.

SAMPLE REQUIRED RESULTS

```
   ID  EmpNo   EmpNo2

    1  0T4/HR 0T4/HR
    1  0T4/HR 2VP/E
    1  0T4/HR xT9/67
    1  0T4/HR 
    1  0T4/HR 
    2  2VP/E 
    2  2VP/E
    2  2VP/E 
    2  2VP/E 
    2  2VP/E 
    3  XT9/67 
    3  XT9/67 
    3  xT9/67 
    3  XT9/67
```

Comment: I want to use EmpNo2 values as a dropdownlist parameter list in a SSRS report. I want to do that way because there is no multiple dataset support in SSRS 2005

Comment: You may wish to add a SSRS tag, then.

Comment: what the hell? give us more info about your schema (tables) and some sample data and some sample result ...

Comment: As Andreas said, some sample data and results are needed, as i read it, you want 100 rows returned for the first two columns and 69 rows for the last column, in the same recordset. Could you clarify please?

Comment: yes Chris, true thats what am trying to accomplish. Basically, the last column should be the distinct values of the second column.

Comment: 69 rows in 100 rows ... how do you imagine the world to be?! :) @chris: that was my first thought either...

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of what you expect the output to look like as what you are currently asking is impossible.

Comment: I have edited the original post to include sample date and required EmpNo2 Values

Comment: You can create multiple data set in reporting services 2005, but each data region can only have one source. So put the drop down list in a different data region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Select id, empno, empno2
from employeestable left outer join (
 SELECT min([id]) as minid
      ,[empno] empno2
  FROM [EmployeesTable]
group by empno) etab2 on employeestable.id = etab2.minid
```

You're saying a subquery won't work, though - why not?

Comment: This might work. But empno2 still returns the same number of rows as empno, now the solution am looking for is to make empno2 return only distinct values of empno. any help on that.

Comment: What you want, is what the above query does (plus NULLS). You cannot have empno2 return less rows: all columns have the same number of rows in a query. Edit: I don't know SSRS, but can't you just use the subquery I have in my answer as the source of your dropdown?

Comment: the problem is that the parameter dropdown has got to pick from the columns returned by the main query(Report Query) as SSRS 2005 does not support multiple datasets in a single report.

When specifiying the source of the dropdown, i can only specify a column from the columns returned by the report query.  __________Am able to do that at the moment but now the dropdown has duplicate options of the same value.

Comment: What happens when you try the query I posted? Do you get a dropdown box with a bunch of NULL lines? That seems like a rather interesting drawback in SSRS, which an SSRS expert should be able to help you with.

Comment: Tobiasopdenbrouw, when i run your query, i get all records(including duplicates). would love to remove the duplicates.

Comment: I see you've added a sample return set, where id is not autoincrementing int (which I was expecting). Still: your expected result set has some results in empno2, the remainder is nulls. Is it really important for SSRS that the results be at the top of the column? In that case, an ORDER BY or smarter query may solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is not clear and I also have very little information. Following is what you need. This can be even better but it is just a try.

```
declare @temp table
(
    uniqueid int identity(1, 1),
    id int,
    empno varchar(50),
    empno2 varchar(50)
)

insert into @temp  select   1,  '0T4/HR', null
insert into @temp select     1,  '0T4/HR' , null
insert into @temp select     1 , '0T4/HR' , null
insert into @temp select     1,  '0T4/HR' , null
insert into @temp select     1,  '0T4/HR'  , null
insert into @temp select     2,  '2VP/E'  , null
insert into @temp select     2,  '2VP/E' , null
insert into @temp select     2,  '2VP/E'  , null
insert into @temp select     2,  '2VP/E'  , null
insert into @temp select     2,  '2VP/E'  , null
insert into @temp select     3,  'XT9/67'  , null
insert into @temp select     3,  'XT9/67'  , null
insert into @temp select     3,  'xT9/67'  , null
insert into @temp select     3,  'XT9/67'  , null

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS id, empno into #temp FROM @temp group by empno, id

update @temp set empno2 = t2.empno
from @temp t inner join #temp t2 on t.uniqueid = t2.id

select * from @temp

drop table #temp
```